# Set a field value based on an expression in DQL

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

I'm trying to update a field in all the lines of a database table, by using an expression as the value. In practice, the field `is_new_arrival` must be set to `true` only if `new_arrival_start_date` and `new_arrival_end_date` are not null and the current day is included into these two dates.

Here is a working native Postgre request of the expected behaviour:

```sql
UPDATE product p SET is_new_arrival =
    p.new_arrival_start_date IS NOT NULL
    AND p.new_arrival_end_date IS NOT NULL
    AND NOW() BETWEEN p.new_arrival_start_date AND p.new_arrival_end_date;
```

Now I would like to use DQL and/or Doctrine QueryBuilder instead of using native Sql, so I tried this:

```php
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$expr = $qb->expr();

$query = $qb
    ->update(Product::class, 'p')
    ->set(
        'p.newArrival',
        $expr->andX(
            $expr->isNotNull('p.newArrivalStartDate'),
            $expr->isNotNull('p.newArrivalEndDate'),
            $expr->between('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()', 'p.newArrivalStartDate', 'p.newArrivalEndDate')
        )
    )
    ->getQuery();

$query->execute();
```

But it gives me this error:

```
In QueryException.php line 54:

  [Syntax Error] line 0, col 90: Error: Expected end of string, got 'IS'

In QueryException.php line 43:

  UPDATE App\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Product p SET p.newArrival = p.newArrivalStartDate IS NOT NULL AND p.newArrivalEndDate IS NOT NULL AND (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
   BETWEEN p.newArrivalStartDate AND p.newArrivalEndDate)
```

It seems that DQL does not handle expressions for `UPDATE ... SET ...` statements. How can I solve this problem and use the QueryBuilder (or DQL directly) to perform this query?

Comment: @goulashsoup The postgres query is working because it is a valid postgre statement: expressions are allowed in `UPDATE` syntax, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html, and `IS`, `NOT`, `AND` are valid expression operators.

Comment: Ok, assuming it valid postgres i strongly suspect that Doctrine can NOT handle that and only supports "regular" SQL-Update statements like the example i have given.

Comment: `UPDATE product p SET is_new_arrival = (CASE WHEN <case> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE)` could work...